# hoping to time-shift existing closed captions on a Vimeo file

Tags: closed-captioning, vimeo

I'm hoping to time-shift existing closed captions on a Vimeo file.

Last month, my office helped produce a college graduation which was livestreamed on Vimeo, with live closed captioning.

The livestream started well before the event, running a simple logo with the event name. So let's say the livestream started at 9:35. The event then began at 10:00 and went off without a hitch.

In hosting the resultant video, the production company lopped off the first twenty-five minutes of footage (the simple logo). The end result is that the captions, which I assume were time stamped, are now a half-hour out of synch.

For another reason, I already plan to download the video and upload it to another Vimeo account, so I'm especially interested in solutions that take advantage of that process.